# What are the various layers from InceptionV3?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, sequential

Hi I'm kind of new to the world of machine learning, but I do know that with sufficient learning one can extract a layer with learned values optimized for a task.

What does all the dense, pooling, batch normalization, etc. all mean in the model summary?

I've worked a little bit with Keras Sequential and I know there are some layer names that I need some simplification on. There's layers like dense, pooling, etc, and I don't know what they mean.

Ultimately, I want to find out which layer type contains those learned values, and maybe create an embedding by fully connecting a layer (I'm not sure how this works)

Furthermore, where in the layer should I extract this layer? I assume it is towards the last parts...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first question is something you should study from a book or online course.

Comment: May you recommend an appropriate (and preferably) free online resource you know of? I'm just in high school, and the university on island doesn't have any ML practitioners